# How to get all pom.xml present under maven repo

Tags: maven, maven-2, pom.xml

Is there any way to get all the pom.xmls which are under http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: Why do need them? Apart from that do you know how many there are? Have you checked https://search.maven.org/stats

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, i would like to take one pom.xml from each artifacts(312,460 unique artifacts ) and parse each pom.xml and read the data from it.

Comment: First if you like to do that you have to handle 4,321,601 cause this are the pom.xml for each groupId/artifactId/version combination and for what purpose would you like to parse them ?

Comment: i would like to know the all java projects and its scm url for each.
and also i dont want 4,321,601 because i need one pom.xml per artifact.

Comment: What are you planning to do with all these URLs?

Comment: On pom per artifacts is simply wrong cause each version has it's own pom file ...so you seemed to misunderstand a pom file...and what groupId/artifactId/version means..

Answer (score 1):

As a best practice, you should not scan and parse poms neither in remote nor local repository. On maven central they already scanned and parsed for you.

Just download nexus-maven-repository-index.gz from [index dir](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.index/) (you need that big file 700M length, other files named nexus-maven-repository-index.XXX.gz are incremental updates)

Then use [Maven Indexer](http://maven.apache.org/maven-indexer/) to unpack index, maven indexer is available as java library and CLI program
As a result of running Maven indexer you'll get ordinary Apache Lucene index, with abitility to update it incrementally.

[Here](https://maven.apache.org/repository/central-index.html) is a documentation, which explains how to unpack index and query data from it. 
Most probably, index contain all the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

For people still having the same question, I have developed a much simpler way to extract maven index indexes that works for most Nexus-based Maven repositories: the [Maven Index Exporter](https://github.com/borisbaldassari/maven-index-exporter).

From there you could simply get a list of poms and download them, if that's what you aim for.

Note however that it's huge: roughly 20 million documents are indexed for Maven Central and the text export is 14GB. There are as of today approximately 6.5 million pom files on Maven Central.